# Why does this python class method not work? (it uses SQLite3)

Tags: python, sql, oop

```
def update_data(self):

    db = sqlite3.connect("SQLite database")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""UPDATE Item SET ? = ? WHERE itemid = ? """,(self.field, self.value, self.ID))
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

The error states that there is a syntax error near the "?" but I'm not seeing what the issue is.

Note: This is a method of a class with fully defined attributes.

Many Thanks

Comment: what do the values of self.field, self.value and self.ID look like?

Comment: They are strings, and the correct input values. I have tested the values by just replacing the values, I would have inputted using the attributes, with the values just themselves within the execute sting and it has worked.
I just need it to work with the attributes instead

Comment: I think you will have to use str.format and validate the input if it is coming from an outside source ,something like  `cursor.execute("""UPDATE Item SET {} = ? WHERE itemid = ? """.format(self.field,(self.value, self.ID)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?` character is not replaced everywhere it appears, only where an expression can be placed. Thus, trying to use `?` for a column name is a sqlite3 syntax error.

You could use

```
query = 'update Item set {} = ? where itemid = ?'.format(self.field)
cursor.execute(query, (self.value, self.ID))
```

where, of course, you'd need to scrub `self.field` for injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had not realised this